# Heroku download pg:backups how to

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I know there are similar questions but the old Heroku's pg:backups addon has been deprecated.

So, following the new docs, I get a public URL that expires after ten minutes after this command:

```
heroku pg:backups public-url backupnumber --app appname
```

What do I do with the public-url? I can't find a comprehensible tutorial online that helps me download the dump file and populate a local database.

I'm using Ubuntu 14 and Postgresql. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `curl` to download the backup using the public-url, e.g.

```
curl -o appname.dump `heroku pg:backups public-url --app appname`
```

Then you can use the Postgres `pg_restore` utility to restore the backup to your local database, e.g.:

```
pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U appuser -d appname appname.dump
```

(substitute your username for `appuser` and your database for `appname`).

There is more detail at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export

Comment: Is the curl command valid on Windows? I'm trying to execute it but I'm getting an error.

Answer (score 15):

There are two different methods:

1. Use `pg:backups:download`

   heroku pg:backups:download -o appname.dump --app appname

> Usage: heroku pg:backups:download [BACKUP_ID]
>
> ```
> downloads database backup
>
>  -a, --app APP       # app to run command against
>  -o, --output OUTPUT # location to download to. Defaults to latest.dump
>  -r, --remote REMOTE # git remote of app to run command against
> ```

2. Use curl with `heroku pg:backups:url`

   curl -o appname.dump `heroku pg:backups:url --app appname`